# CORS issue with Next.js and Express: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, next.js

I have a simple Express app on Heroku that sends emails. I have a client on Next.js/Vercel.

My backend configuration looks like this:

```
const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

...

app.options("/", cors(), function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "myclient.site");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.end();
});


app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
//code
})
```

And my client request function looks like this:

```
const sendInfo = (data) => {
  axios("heroku.api", {
    method: "post",
    withCredentials: true,
    data: {
    ...
    },
  });
};
```

The exact error response I'm getting is this,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'heroku.api' from origin 'client.site' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

Comment: Why are you using the middleware _and_ trying to set the headers manually? See the docs for examples to follow: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors

Comment: I was trying a combo in hopes it would work, as I had tried the given example. I'm trying it now as well, and it still isn't working.

Comment: Why not write the backend also in Next.js?

Comment: @brc-dd that is what i did - I have no idea why the cors issue was occurring. It was set up the same way other apps have worked. I think something is happening that has to do with being hosted on Vercel. 

But with the API endpoints in NExt, everything is fine.